# What is Passcrypt in Citrix Netscaler cli option?

Tags: cryptography, ssl-certificate, citrix, netscaler

I was going through Citrix Netscaler documentation to renew certificate for Netscaler so it is using Passcrypt as argument for private key but no where mentioned how is it being generated and how is it being used on Netscaler so does anyone faced same problem or or having any idea about it?

Doc:https://developer-docs.citrix.com/projects/netscaler-command-reference/en/10.5/ssl/ssl-certkey/ssl-certkey/

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: It seems that if you use an encrypted container file (.p12, .pfx, PEM) then `passcrypt` contains the container password. But maybe try asking the question again on https://discussions.citrix.com